# How to make Spotify/Yt/YtMusic bottom slide-up panel show in every page of my flutter app

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a music app, and I want to add the bottom slide-up feature from Spotify to it using the **sliding_up_panel** dependency. And I place the widget in my **bottom navigation bar** of the scaffold in the main app tree. But for some reason I don't seem to know, the sliding up widget always disappears when I call **Navigator.push**. I want a way to make it stay there no matter the screen I'm on.

I tried making the **body** of the main app tree, the member of a list, something like;

```
List pages = [
    Home(), Search(), Library(), Settings(), AlbumPage(), PlaylistPage(), ArtistHomePage()
];


return Scaffold(
   body: pages[currentPage],
   bottomNavigationBar: ....,
);
```

And in the **bottomNavigationBar** I had a column with the sliding_up_panel on top of the real bottom navigation bar widget. So anytime I tapped on the **Library** icon, the **currentPage** changes to 2 and when I tapped on any album, the currentPage will change to 4 and so on. This worked and the bottom nav bar and the sliding_up_panel were on all pages, but when I searched for an album and tap on it, it sends me to the page and I see the bottom widgets alright but when I click back, instead of it to go to the previous **search** page, it closes the app. And I understand why, but even though it solves the previous problem, it creates a bigger one and I'm not ready for it. All help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

So i suggest you to do this, instead of using the "sliding_up_panel", you can directly use flutter animation:

1. Create a separate dart file for a "Bottom player".
2. Call the BottomPlayer() from the scaffold of your home page.
3. wrap the bottom player with gesture detector and by using the "onTap" of gesture detector, you can navigate to a new screen by your desired animation like this:

   Navigator.push(context,PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context,
   animation, secondaryAnimation) => Player(color:Colors.blue,),
   transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child)
   {const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
   end = Offset.zero;
   const curve = Curves.decelerate;
   var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve:
   curve));
   var offsetAnimation = animation.drive(tween);
   return SlideTransition(position: offsetAnimation, child: child);
   },
   ),
   );

here, change the "Player(color: Colors.blue,)" to your desired new page.

4. To show bottom player or any other widget at every screen, you need to use pageStorage. here is how you can do it:

   //define in the homepage class
   int _selectedTab = 0;
   final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

   final List pages = [
   StartScreen(
   key: PageStorageKey('StartScreen'),
   ),
   SearchScreen(
   key: PageStorageKey('SearchScreen'),
   ),
   LibraryScreen(
   key: PageStorageKey('LibraryScreen'),
   ),
   PremiumScreen(
   key: PageStorageKey('PremiumScreen'),
   ),
   ];

   Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => Theme(
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
   ),
   child: BottomNavigationBar(
   onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedTab = index),
   currentIndex: _selectedTab,
   type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
   selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
   backgroundColor: Colors.black,
   showSelectedLabels: false,
   showUnselectedLabels: false,
   unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
   items: const [
   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
   BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label:
   'Search'),
   BottomNavigationBarItem(
   icon: Icon(Icons.library_music_outlined), label: 'Library'),
   BottomNavigationBarItem(
   icon: Icon(Icons.sports_volleyball_outlined), label:
   'Premium'),
   ],
   ),
   );

   // build function
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedTab),
   body: Column(
   children: [
   Flexible(
   child: PageStorage(
   child: pages[_selectedTab],
   bucket: bucket,
   ),
   ),
   // any other widgets
   ],
   ),
   );
   }